# Netbeans: Java Swing: How can I change the datatype of JComboBox Items

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jcombobox

I added a JComboBox to my JFrame inside the Design View and the datatype of its items is by default String:

```
private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> items;
```

The variable declaration is automatically added to the Source and cannot be edited.
Can someone tell me how I change the datatype of the items inside the Design View? Or do I have to create the JComboBox Component inside the Source myself?

(I'm using NetBeans IDE 8.2; Java Version 1.8)

Comment: check propertis

Comment: Thank you! When I was searching I just checked Properties-> Properties. I did not check Properties->Code.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `Properties` -> `Code` -> `Type Parameters`

[image]