# Changing datatypes of JComboBox elements

Tags: java, swing, combobox, jcombobox

I need to make a JComboBox that is filled with JRadioButtons as its entries. So it looks like a drop down box that has several JRadioButtons in it that can be chosen. So I used the following code :

```
JComboBox<JRadioButton> deg=new JComboBox();
DefaultComboBoxModel<JRadioButton> degModel=new DefaultComboBoxModel<>();
degModel.addElement(new JRadioButton("This Button));
deg.setModel(degModel);
```

So naturally, I would expect a drop down menu of JRadioButtons but instead I happen to see something like this :

[image]

So it seems like for some reason, the entry type of the JComboBox hasn't changed although I tried to set the types to JRadioButtons and it's still trying to make a JComboBox of String datatypes and hence is showing the toString of the mentioned JRadioButton.

I also found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43892438/netbeans-java-swing-how-can-i-change-the-datatype-of-jcombobox-items) related to the issue but it's only an option on NetBeans (as far as I know) and it's quite weird how changing a built-in compiler option is related to the functionality of a certain class.

Can anyone help me fix this? Any help would be appreciated!
(I also need the JRadioButton to change isSelected when clicked on)
P.S. : Any alternative to JComboBox in this case is also appreciated.

Comment: No time for detail but what you need is a Model that is boolean and you need a *renderer* (google it) that gives you radio buttons - two quite different and distinct parts to carry out

Comment: The model can hold any type of data so there is no need to change the model. However, yes, you do need a custom renderer to paint the data in the model. So there is only one issue to solve. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Providing a custom renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer). Note, you will also need to add an ActionListener to the combo box to change the state of the radio button when it is clicked.

Comment: **Use a JMenu containing JCheckBoxMenuItems** instead of a JComboBox.  You are misusing JComboBox and you are misusing JRadioButtons.  JRadioButtons are explicitly designed to allow **only one** in a group to be selected at any time.  Even if you force them to work differently, you will end up confusing users of the application, who expect that something which looks like a radio button actually behaves like a radio button.  And while it is possible to embed components in a JComboBox, JComboBox is not designed to work that way.