# Modify data type of JComboBox in Swing

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, netbeans-8

I was trying to modify the data type of a combo box named `cbLicense` in Swing. In this case, I wanna change from `String` to `CustomerItem` which is a class. I use Swing design, so I selected the combo box, went to Properties/Code/TypeParameters. But the problem is that on the `Generated Code` section, there's still a line:

`cbLicense.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" }));`

This line has an incompatible type error. So how do I fix it? Do I need to add each `CustomerItem` object into `cbLicense` via Design view? Because the `CustomerItem` value is retrieved from the database.

Find the way to customize combo box in Swing

Comment: Is "Swing design" the name of the sofware you're using to design Swing forms?

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22652008/4725875) may assist you.

Comment: @MauricePerry No. I use Swing design in Netbeans 8.2.

Comment: @DevilsHnd Thank you. But I use the design option in Netbeans, which is drag and drop. So some code is auto-generated and cannot be modified.

Comment: @Lucia it can be modified: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43892689/7036419

Comment: @MauricePerry Yes, I've already followed that link. But when I drag a new combo box, the line `cbLicense.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" }));` is created automatically. Even I changed data type after that, that line is still there.

Comment: Use `Custom creation code` in the `Code` tab of the combobox properties

Comment: @Lucia or right-click on the combobox, and select "Customize code..."

Comment: @MauricePerry I have declared CustomerItem outside of the generation code section. Now I added those code into Custom creation code:
`cbLicense = CustomerItem[] items = new CustomerItem[3];
items[0] = new CustomerItem("oh", false);
items[1] = new CustomerItem("My", false);
items[2] = new CustomerItem("God", false);

        DefaultComboBoxModel<CustomerItem> model = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(items);
        cbLicense.setModel(model);
        cbLicense.setRenderer(new RenderCheckComboBox());`

Comment: @MauricePerry I do apologise if it's hard to read my comment. I dont know to format code on comment. But an error has occured on the line: `cbLicense = CustomerItem[] items = new CustomerItem[3];`. And with this way, can I retrieve value from the database into combo box?

Comment: Try `new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new CustomerItem[]{
new CustomerItem("oh", false), new CustomerItem("My", false), new CustomerItem("God", false)

})`

Comment: @MauricePerry It automatically added `cbLicense =` before your code.
        `cbLicense = DefaultComboBoxModel<CustomerItem> model = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new CustomerItem[]{
            new CustomerItem("oh", false),
            new CustomerItem("My", false),
            new CustomerItem("God", false)
        });
        cbLicense.setModel(model);
        cbLicense.setRenderer(new RenderCheckComboBox());`

Comment: @MauricePerry Oh, this is `Custom creation Code` so it will automatically add `cbLicense =`. But I wanna make changes on `cbLicense.setModel`.

Comment: @Lucia two possible solutions: 1) right-click on the combobox and select "Customize code...", 2) `new JComboBox<>(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new CustomerItem[]{ new CustomerItem("oh", false), new CustomerItem("My", false), new CustomerItem("God", false)  }))`

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the combobox, and select "Customize code...":

[image]